# How to read and display my log file info in application using Log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using Log4net in my application.

Can anyone please explain how to read my log files(Txt) and show it in my application.because my log files are there in another server.

What will be the config settings to read the log files from the server and show it in the C# application.
This is the code have used to write the logs.

```
    <log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="\\10.8.8.87\temp\logs.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%identity---- %date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30795/C-WPF-Log4Net-Viewer

Comment: i need a code for the viewer what you refer a link.because i can not  use Log4netViewer or Log4netDashboard.i have to create dynamic viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an rollingfile appender you can better use for example a sql appender to log your exceptions to a database and from your application you can query the database. On this page you can find some config examples:

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Comment: I shouldn't use database to store my logs.so give some other solution to read logfile.